# VBA to clear the contents of the sheet retaining heading and formulas

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I have an excel sheet which has headings with lots of data below from Column A to FQ. Columns GA to GQ have headings and have formulas below it to extract relevant information from the initial columns. My requirement is to clear the data from the table keeping the headings and formulas intact, please note that this data is not stored as a table, its a normal range.

Comment: So what's your question? Can we help you with anything you've tried?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

How about the following:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A
    ws.Range("A2:FQ" & LastRow).ClearContents
End Sub
```